# Why does the list of questions show the editor as if it was the author?

Tags: discussion, questions, question-lists

On Drupal Answers, the lists of questions (e.g. [active](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/) or [hot](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/?tab=hot) questions) show the person who made edit on a question as if it was the author, so I find this quite confusing.
You can see that [googletorp](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/190/googletorp), [kiamlaluno](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/199/kiamlaluno) or [Berdir](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/31/berdir) are omnipresent, but in fact they don't ask question; they just edit the questions to correct presentation, tags, etc.

I think it would be better to let the original poster name there and it would be gratifying for new users to see their name instead of a moderator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the "active," and the "hot" pages don't report who is the author of the question, but the last user who answered the question, edited the question, or edited an answer.
If you compare those pages with https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions, you will notice that only in the latter there is a phrase like "asked 2 hours ago."

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

When you don't read "asked," then the reported user is not the author of the question.

Comment: Yes sure but why isn't this consistent across lists ? This site is about asking questions not editing/retagging so authors should be put first and maybe answerers to. Maybe have something like `asked by X 1 hour ago, answered by Y 30 mn ago`.

Comment: @tostinni Because the pages have different purposes. If they had the same purpose, then there would be just a page, instead of two.

Comment: I do understand their purpose, that's why one is "active" the other is "newest" but I don't understand the value of displaying the name of the editor (and it's not a personnal beef against you guys ;) )... I can definitely live with this but it seems very strange to me. It's like if I see in a museum a painting and get the name of the curator before the artist ;)

Comment: @tostinni It's probably because in the active questions list, the question on the top had a recent answer (which includes also an answer that has been recently edited), or has been recently edited;  in such cases, who wrote the question (who doesn't change) is probably less important than who made the recent edit.  If who asked the question would have been considered always the most important information, then all the question lists would have reported the author of the question.

Comment: `If who asked the question would have been considered always the most important information, then all the question lists would have reported the author of the question.` I totally agree to that but when there's no answer, I don't feel the editor is so important to be promoted instead of the author. This [question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4886/rss-feed-not-updating-using-feeds-module) show you in the [list](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active) instead of the poster. Anyway I'm splitting hairs here ;)

Comment: @tostinni That just means that you are not one of the developers of the SE software. `:-)`